# SQL Merge and output in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge, output

I'm merging 2 tables and I want that if the cell is update the field would be marked as "updated" my code:

```
 MERGE [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testine2] te
    USING [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testinus] bo
    ON te.itemid = bo.itemid
    AND te.itemname <> bo.itemname
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET te.itemname = bo.itemname
     OUTPUT
        $action
       into  [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testine2] (busena);
    SELECT * FROM [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testine2];
```

Result I get:

```
Itemid  Itemname Busena 
100001  TEST      NULL 
NULL    Null      UPADTE
```

The result I want:

```
Itemid  Itemname Busena
100001  TEST      UPDATE
```

Comment: Plz share your table structure?? Also which DB you are using??

Comment: The table [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testine2] is  Itemid  Itemname Busena  and [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testinus] is Itemid  Itemname its mssql 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want that if the cell is update the field would be marked as
>   "updated"

There is no reason to use output. Just set the column value in the update.

```
MERGE [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testine2] te
    USING [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testinus] bo
    ON te.itemid = bo.itemid
    AND te.itemname <> bo.itemname
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET te.itemname = bo.itemname,
          te.Busena = 'UPDATE';

SELECT * FROM [ITWORKS].[dbo].[Testine2];
```